# Slim 3 Framework - How to return a generated file?

Tags: php, download, slim-3

In the code snippet below the content of the `$file` array is rendered in the browser.

The code works but I think there must be a better way to transform the binary string into a stream to send to the browser.

```
if (is_array($file)) {

    $filename=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 \\._-]+/', '', $file['filename']);

    // -- This feels like a hack
    $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    fwrite($stream, $file['content']);
    rewind($stream);
    // --

    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', $file['mimetype'])
        ->withHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
        ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"')
        ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
        ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
        ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
        ->withBody(new \Slim\Http\Stream($stream));
}
```

What is the proper way to transform the content into a stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using the `Response` object’s `getBody()` method.

```
if (is_array($file)) {

    if (strlen($file['filename'])) {
        $filename=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 \\._-]+/', '', $file['filename']);
    }

    $content = $response->getBody();
    $content->write($file['content']);

    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', $file['mimetype'])
        ->withHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
        ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"')
        ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
        ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
        ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public');

}
```